# Multiple Types of Users on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and have been following the tutorial. 
But I need more information.

I'm building an application that will allow access to various types of users, they are, students, parents, teachers and Administration (all have the same attributes) 
So far I have a model for User, which has fields, Email and Password, which serve as credentials to log into the site ..

Then I have a template for each type of user. 
Model Student 
Model Teacher 
....

What I wanted to know was how do I register a user, referring to each type of user, and I already have a table User.

I've been searching and I realized that using 'devise' would be a viable solution, but do not quite understand how this works.

Someone explain to me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 40):

There are several ways to approach this problem, as other answers indicate. First, make sure you understand the difference between *authentication*, (creating a user and logging in), and role-based *authorization* (controlling access to different parts of the web application depending on the user's role). You can implement authentication yourself but most Rails developers use the Devise gem because it is robust, full-featured, and well-tested. Authorization can be implemented with simple additions to a User model, though developers often use the [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gems for complex applications.

For the use case you describe, I recommend implementing a very basic form of role-based authorization in your User model. First you'll have to create a User model using Devise.

A new feature of Active Record, Enum, introduced in Rails 4.1, is the simplest way to implement role-based authorization.

Create a migration:

```
$ rails generate migration AddRoleToUsers role:integer
```

The migration will look like this:

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end
```

Add code to your User model to implement the Enum:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:student, :parent, :teacher, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :student
  end

end
```

You define the names of the roles, and if necessary, can change the names as needed (the integer values stored with each user record remain unchanged). Active Record will restrict the assignment of the attribute to a collection of predefined values, so you don’t have to add any code to restrict the names of the roles to a defined set. Best of all, enums come with a set of convenience methods that allow you to directly query the role without any extra code. For the enum attribute shown above, you can use these methods:

```
User.roles # => {"student"=>0, "parent"=>1, "teacher"=>2, "admin"=>1} # list all roles
user.student! # make a student user
user.student? # => true # query if the user is a student
user.role # => "student" # find out the user’s role
@users = User.student # obtain an array of all users who are students
user.role = 'foo' # ArgumentError: 'foo' is not a valid, we can’t set invalid roles
```

You can use the conditionals in a controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied."
    end
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Or use it in a view:

```
<% if current_user.parent? %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Grade Reports', some_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

In general, if access control adds a lot of code to a controller, you're well-advised to use  [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit), because you can move the complex authorization logic into a central location segregated from the controllers ("skinny controllers"). However, if your needs are as simple as you describe, role-based authorization in the controller is optimal.

I've written a [Rails Pundit](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise-pundit/) tutorial that compares both approaches and provides greater detail on simple role-based authorization as well as role-based authorization with Pundit.

Comment: Very good answer! A little remark: I got an error saying that I can't have a field ":parent" inside the enum, because this class already has a method "parent", which is defined by Active Record.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I like to use the custom code instead of gem. I just wonder what if I want the user to have multi-roles. for ex. user has role: :teacher and :admin

Comment: Nice. Also, since the default role is set after initialize. The migration could include a default value, instead of using a callback. something like:
`add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0`

Comment: Is it still necessary/possible to define the user_id of User model as foreign key in Student model/other models? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well, here is how I would implement it.

1) create Account model and add a polymorphic reference in its migration like this

```
  class Account < ActiveRecord:Migration
    def change
      create_table :accounts do |t|
        t.references :user, :polymorphic => true
        t.column :name, :string
      end
    end
  end
```

2) In each model class, for instance student class I would add the following line of code

```
  class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :account, :as => :user
  end
```

3) In Account model class

```
  class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
  end
```

4) Use devise generator for Account model.

5) The big challenge is creating a new Student, basically you will be creating an Account record then assign this Account record to the newly created Student record.

a) There are 2 ways to do so:
      * Using nested forms.
      * Using a simple form and make the controller do the work.

I would encourage the second option, choose what fits you best and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Maybe i wasnt very clear, but i already have a page to create a user, through my User Model (i can do login and logout, and validate all data for this 'table'). Now, i want to have the data of both model (User and UserType - Student/Parents/Admin/etc) in the same page and then save all data to their respective models.

Answer (score 1):

If different app permissions is what you need, perhaps you want to assign roles to your users. This can be accomplished in many different ways. An easy one is to use Rolify gem: https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Answer (score 0):

In its most simple form, you want to be able to select the type of user when registering it.

```
class User
  belongs_to: user_type
end

class UserType
  has_many: users
end
```

Based on that simple one-to-many relationship, you can pass in the user_type in the form to the controller and let the controller take care of creating/associating objects

```
user = User.create(params[:user])
user.user_type = UserType.find(params[:user][:user_type])
```

That's some very simple and quickly put together code with intention to make my point a bit clearer.

Comment: `type`attribute is reserved for single table inheritance, what could be appropriate in this case, but at least you should specify that this answer implies STI and Student and Teacher model should inherit from User.

Comment: thanks for your comment @CV-Gate. I've modified my answer. Here I'm not using STI.